# Unable to start Remote debugger as it crashes immediately

Tags: debugging, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-debugging, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

Last few weeks me and few colleagues are encountering crashes of Remote debugger tools in case we're using them through Remote desktop (e.g. you install Windows, install Remote debugger, start and it will crash in < 1s).

Issue occurs time to time, most often on configuration Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 or WinServer 2012 R2 Standard. We're mainly using `VS2015 remote debugger tools` but when this issue occurs then it behave same for `VS2015/2013/2012` remote debuggers and it's there forever unless OS is reinstalled.

When you let app crash and start it again as new instance without closing original crashing you've got alert that default port 4020 is occupied by another application so it seems it's able to occupy port before crash doing something before crash. Second instance in picture is just for deeper explanation - main issue it's crashing at all even when just one instance is running.

Currently it seems for some Memory access violation exception in wsdapi.dll

Did you ever met similar behavior and found way how move forward?

Issue itself is pretty similar to this one dead thread http://www.yqcomputer.com/4_469b4b74a9aced45_1.htm

On picture below 
- debug program option just doesn't work in way it's not able to step into VS.
- Check online... just finds nothing and collects info about my operating system configuration prepared to be sent to Microsoft.

Only additional information we're able to get are from those Event application log but those are pretty brief as well.

```
Faulting application name: msvsmon.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564e96d6
Faulting module name: wsdapi.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7ca31
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000051e8e
Faulting process id: 0x16a0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d170895f8a7b52
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\wsdapi.dll
Report Id: 9d409094-dc7c-11e5-a94d-00155d1a2544
```

[image: crashscreen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is currently solution for setup you describe. I was having pretty same issue happening all the time on one of my Windows Server 2008R2 SP1 virtual machine. Unfortunately I wasn't able figure out why it was happening but after I've replaced my 2008R2 with 2012 I never hit the issue again.

Given it was crashing with reference to `wsdapi.dll` I guess it was some major in incompatibility between `VS2015` and Windows Server 2008R2 (pretty old as it was starting with `.NET 3.5`) and so upgrade is best solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed we ended up with similar conclusion for now. After we started to get rid of old machines issue started to decline. I though it would still be good to know what was original issue but I'd say it was combination of what you're stating with some environmental issue since it was failing just on 'some' 2008R2 machines while some were working.